# Is an external void pointer to a local variable safe?

Tags: c, pointers, void-pointers, local-variables

I've one struct declared as above

```c
struct foo {
  void * elem;
};
```

I want to manage the free() of elem in this struct, but I don't know which is the type of the elem, so I'm making a `void *` to manage all data types.
Is it safe to assign to foo.elem a pointer to a local variable?

For example, are these methods safe?

```c
// Method 1
struct foo * get_foo() {
  int a = 10;
  struct foo x = malloc(sizeof(struct foo));
  x.elem = &a;
  return x;
}

// Method 2
void get_foo(struct foo x) {
  int a = 10;
  x.elem = &a;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here. Void pointers that you don't know the type of are not very useful. Anyway, in both cases, `a` won't exist after you return from the function and you have a stale pointer -- a non-null pointer to illegal memory. It doesn't matter in your second case, though, because `x` will go out of scope, too.

Comment: Both are wrong. You cannot guarantee what will be happened the local addresses.

Comment: Please ensure you post code that compiles — the structure definition was missing two semicolons

Comment: Note that "Method 2" modifies the copy of a `struct foo` that was passed to the function, but that is not reflected back in the calling function. You'd need to pass a `struct foo *` and change the code to achieve that. But you can't safely return a pointer to a local variable — `a` — and you can't use `free()` safely on a pointer to a local variable because it wasn't allocated as if by `malloc()`. So the whole second method is pointless from start to finish. There are similar problems in "Method 1", but there you do return a pointer to the allocated `struct foo` (but you can't free `x->elem`).

Comment: You need to be sure that your examples are correct and accurate illustrations of what you asking and do what you think they doo (even if it is unsafe); otherwise  you will get accurate but unhelpful answers such as that already posted.

Comment: This is a clear X-Y problem.  You are asking about an aspect of your "solution" to some unstated problem.  Your solution is flawed  - it is never safe.  But knowing that you are no further forward.  You should instead ask a question about what your are trying to achieve, not about how you _think_ you might achieve it.

Comment: Emme Developer, Have you tried compiling code: `struct foo x = malloc(sizeof(struct foo));`?

Comment: "_I want to manage the free() of elem_" makes no sense in the context of your examples where `elem` does not point to dynamically allocated memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of the validity of your code examples as exemplars of what you are asking about (neither illustrates the question correctly), it is *never* valid or safe to retain a pointer to a variable outside of the *lifetime* of that variable.

Dereferencing such a pointer is undefined behaviour, in principle anything could happen.  In practice what does happen is the memory for that variable becomes available for reuse and if you read it via the pointer it may no longer contain the same value, and if you write it, you may be modifying some unrelated data object or corrupting the call stack - the behaviour in either case is *non-deterministic*; which is no more useful that undefined behaviour.

Note that it is an issue of *lifetime* not of *scope*.  A pointer to a *local* `static` is valid.

Comment: @ikegami : Agreed. I have modified the text accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The first doesn't compile. It's not safe code, in the sense that it's not code at all.

The second just uselessly modifies local variable `x`. It's safe, since it effectively does absolutely nothing, and there's nothing inherently harmful about doing nothing.

Comment: All true, but rather a comment of the quality of the question than an answer perhaps.

Comment: @Clifford, I don't know why you'd say that as this literally answers the question. It might not be the question the OP meant to ask, but until it's changed, it's the question that was asked.

Comment: It does not address the question in the title, it addresses the flaws in the illustrative examples.  Ideally the OP would correct that in the question (don't hold your breath), which would invalidate this answer.  My point is you have adressed errors in the question not the question the OP _ intended_ to ask.